# How do I pass an object by value?

Tags: parameter-passing, pass-by-reference, d, pass-by-value

```
import std.stdio;

class IntegerContainer
{
    public int Integer = 1;
}

void DoubleInteger(IntegerContainer Container)
{
    Container.Integer *= 2;
}

void main()
{
    IntegerContainer Container = new IntegerContainer; // Internal integer defaults to one.
    DoubleInteger(Container); // Internal integer changes to two inside the function.
    writefln(Container.Integer); // Prints "2."
}
```

In D, reference vs. value is a trait of the type, rather than of the function parameter.  Coming from C++, this feels really bad to me.

It looks like there's a `ref` keyword to force pass-by-reference for functions accepting `struct`s.  Is there such an equivalent for passing `class`es by value?

For example, let's say I want to make a function function that returns a sorted copy of a custom container class.  In C++, that's as simple as using `Foo Sorted(Foo Object)`, as opposed to `Foo Sort(Foo& Object)`.  I see no way of doing this in D without manually copying the object.

Comment: even with objects of classes, it's still pass-by-value, because it's the reference that you're passing, by value

Comment: @newacct I think everyone knows what is meant by "pass-by-value."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Classes are reference types by design. They're not supposed to be passed by value. It's exactly the same with Java and C#. However, unlike Java and C#, D has full-fledged user-defined value types as well, since it has structs (C# has structs too, but they're *much* more limited). The fact that C++ conflates the two causes problems such as [object slicing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing).

Now, obviously there *are* times when you want to copy a reference type. The solution to that is [cloning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloning_%28programming%29). You give your class a `clone` function which returns a copy of the object it's called on. That way, you can copy it when you need to, and it only gets copied when you need it to be. Java and C# have a standard `clone` function that most types implement, but for whatever reason D does not. I'm not sure why. But it's still easy enough to declare such a function yourself for your own types. It just isn't going to be on `Object`, which would allow you to use it on pretty much any class object without caring what the actual type was like you can do in Java and C#. You could always create a copy constructor instead, if you prefer, but it's less flexible, because you have to know the type of the object being copied, whereas with `clone`, it can be any type derived from the type that `clone` returns (which would be `Object` in the case of Java and C# but would be whatever you decide in D, since the function is non-standard).

Comment: IIRC a few things in D (arrays) have a `dup` property.

Comment: Yes, but classes don't usually implement such a function. It could be though that it will become typical to implement a function called `dup` rather than `clone` though (there aren't many classes in the standard library yet, so I don't think that a particular clone function has been at all standard yet). Regardless, it's the same concept either way.

Comment: Ah. yes. I should be more clear: because other things use `dup` it may be a good idea to not call the function `clone`. Keeping the name the same may make template code cleaner.

Answer (score 4):

Yeah, just use a struct instead of a class.

But if you want to copy an *object*, then you have to implement cloning yourself. Note that the D designers didn't make this up; it's the exact same way in C#, and pretty similar in Java. The goal is to prevent objects from being copied excessively, which is seen as a downside of C++ (since it's very hidden in the code).

Comment: @Maxpm: See the 1st sentence of my 2nd paragraph.

Answer (score 3):

Even in C++ this:

```
Foo Sorted(Foo Object)
```

is not that useful. What if the Object is already sorted and you don't need to create a copy?

In D you will need to provide `clone()` of some such for your class and call it if needed.

Otherwise use structs as Mehrdad mentioned.

Edit: It is not clear what exactly "copying the object" should do. If it has array of objects inside shall it clone that array? And what about object references it contains? It is actually good that monsieur Walter Bright, author of D, did not provide copying of class instances by default.